# Implementing 'gulp-file-include' in 'yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules, gulp-watch

I'm using [yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) and I've added [gulp-file-include](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) plugin. I've generated vanilla `gulpfile.babel.js` by using yeoman, but I'm not sure how to implement this plugin (file-include) in this file (gulpfile.babel.js) in such a way that it works will all commands (e.g. `gulp`, `gulp serve`) seamlessly.

I've tried to implement it with no luck. Following is the unmodified code from my `gulpfile.babel.js` file:

```
// generated on 2015-07-07 using generator-gulp-webapp 1.0.2
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import del from 'del';
import {stream as wiredep} from 'wiredep';

const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();
const reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

function lint(files, options) {
  return () => {
    return gulp.src(files)
      .pipe(reload({stream: true, once: true}))
      .pipe($.eslint(options))
      .pipe($.eslint.format())
      .pipe($.if(!browserSync.active, $.eslint.failAfterError()));
  };
}
const testLintOptions = {
  env: {
    mocha: true
  },
  globals: {
    assert: false,
    expect: false,
    should: false
  }
};

gulp.task('lint', lint('app/scripts/**/*.js'));
gulp.task('lint:test', lint('test/spec/**/*.js', testLintOptions));

gulp.task('html', ['styles'], () => {
  const assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']});

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.minifyCss({compatibility: '*'})))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({conditionals: true, loose: true})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('images', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.if($.if.isFile, $.cache($.imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true,
      // don't remove IDs from SVGs, they are often used
      // as hooks for embedding and styling
      svgoPlugins: [{cleanupIDs: false}]
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.end();
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', () => {
  return gulp.src(require('main-bower-files')({
    filter: '**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'
  }).concat('app/fonts/**/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/fonts'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/*.*',
    '!app/*.html'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist']));

gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'fonts'], () => {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
  ]).on('change', reload);

  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', () => {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['dist']
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('serve:test', () => {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port: 9000,
    ui: false,
    server: {
      baseDir: 'test',
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch('test/spec/**/*.js').on('change', reload);
  gulp.watch('test/spec/**/*.js', ['lint:test']);
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', () => {
  gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

  gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      exclude: ['bootstrap-sass'],
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['lint', 'html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras'], () => {
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*').pipe($.size({title: 'build', gzip: true}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], () => {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

**UPDATE # 1**

I've tried adding this line:

```
.pipe($.if('*.html', $.fileinclude({prefix: '@@', basepath: '@file'})))
```

after this line in `html` task:

```
.pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({conditionals: true, loose: true})))
```

but it is of no use, running `gulp html` gives a long error.

**UPDATE # 2**

Issue Solved!

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I followed this procedure with some customization: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/jade.md